Mern app post requests reciveing 408 timeout error
I have a form that is supposed to send user input to my mongodb cluster:
// Registration.jsx
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

const Registration = () => {
  const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
  const [password, setPassword] = useState('');
  const [error, setError] = useState('');
  const [successMessage, setSuccessMessage] = useState('');

  const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    try {
      // Validation logic (you can use a library like Yup for form validation)
      if (!email || !password) {
        setError('Email and password are required.');
        return;
      }
      console.log("Test");
      // Registration API call
      const response = await axios.post('/api/auth/register', { email, password });
      console.log(response);
      setSuccessMessage(response.data.message);
    } catch (error) {
      setError(error.response.data.message);
    }
  }

  return (
    <div className="container">
      <div className="row">
        <div className="col-md-6 offset-md-3">
          <h2>Registration</h2>
          {error && <div className="alert alert-danger">{error}</div>}
          {successMessage && <div className="alert alert-success">{successMessage}</div>}
          <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
            <div className="mb-3">
              <label htmlFor="email" className="form-label">Email address</label>
              <input type="email" className="form-control" id="email" value={email} onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)} required />
            </div>
            <div className="mb-3">
              <label htmlFor="password" className="form-label">Password</label>
              <input type="password" className="form-control" id="password" value={password} onChange={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)} required />
            </div>
            <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary">Register</button>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Registration;


On submit the request will start and then crash after a while with the 408 error code, I've tested on both my actual frontend and postman and got the same result. I'm not sure why the request is timing out. Any help is greatly appreciated ill include any code I feel is relevant below:
//auth.js
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
const User = require('../models/user.js');
const  registerValidation  = require('../middleware/validation.js');
const { validationResult } = require('express-validator');


console.log("This is before all routes");
//Register Route
router.post('/register', registerValidation, async (req, res) => {
  // Validate request body
  const errors = validationResult(req);
  if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
    return res.status(400).json({ errors: errors.array() });
  }

  const { email, password } = req.body;
  console.log("This log is just before the try catch for creating the new user.");
  try {
    // Check if user already exists
    let user = await User.findOne({ email });
    if (user) {
      return res.status(400).json({ msg: 'User already exists' });
    }

    // Create new user
    user = new User({
      email,
      password
    });

    console.log(user);
    // Hash password
    const salt = await bcrypt.genSalt(10);
    user.password = await bcrypt.hash(password, salt);

    // Save user to database
    await user.save();
    console.log("This console log is right after the user gets saved to the database")
    // Generate JWT token
    const payload = {
      user: {
        id: user.id
      }
    };

    jwt.sign(
      payload,
      process.env.JWT_SECRET,
      { expiresIn: '1d' },
      (err, token) => {
        if (err) throw err;
        res.json({ token });
      }
    );
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err.message);
    res.status(500).send('Server Error');
  }

  res.status(200).json({ message: 'Registration successful', email });
  console.log("200 msg sent");
});

//Email Verification Route
router.get('/verify/:token', async (req, res) => {
    const token = req.params.token;
  
    try {
      // Verify token
      const decoded = jwt.verify(token, process.env.JWT_SECRET);
  
      // Update user's verified status
      await User.findByIdAndUpdate(decoded.user.id, { verified: true });
  
      res.json({ msg: 'Email verified successfully' });
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(err.message);
      res.status(500).send('Server Error');
    }
  });

// Login Route
router.post('/login', async (req, res) => {
    const { email, password } = req.body;
  
    try {
      // Check if user exists
      let user = await User.findOne({ email });
      if (!user) {
        return res.status(400).json({ msg: 'Invalid Credentials' });
      }
  
      // Check if password matches
      const isMatch = await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password);
      if (!isMatch) {
        return res.status(400).json({ msg: 'Invalid Credentials' });
      }
  
      // Check if user is verified
      if (!user.verified) {
        return res.status(400).json({ msg: 'Please verify your email' });
      }
  
      // Generate JWT token
      const payload = {
        user: {
          id: user.id
        }
      };
  
      jwt.sign(
        payload,
        process.env.JWT_SECRET,
        { expiresIn: '1d' },
        (err, token) => {
          if (err) throw err;
          res.json({ token });
        }
      );
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(err.message);
      res.status(500).send('Server Error');
    }
  });

// Forgot password route
router.post('/forgot-password', async (req, res) => {
    const { email } = req.body;
  
    try {
      // Check if user exists
      const user = await User.findOne({ email });
      if (!user) {
        return res.status(400).json({ msg: 'User not found' });
      }
  
      // Generate verification code
      const verificationCode = Math.floor(100000 + Math.random() * 900000);
  
      // Implement logic to send verification code to user's email using SendGrid
  
      res.json({ msg: 'Verification code sent to your email' });
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(err.message);
      res.status(500).send('Server Error');
    }
  });
  
// Verify Code route
router.post('/verify-code', async (req, res) => {
    const { email, verificationCode } = req.body;
  
    try {
      // Check if user exists
      const user = await User.findOne({ email });
      if (!user) {
        return res.status(400).json({ msg: 'User not found' });
      }
  
      // Check if verification code matches
      if (user.verificationCode !== verificationCode) {
        return res.status(400).json({ msg: 'Invalid verification code' });
      }
  
      // If verification code matches, update user's verified status
      user.verified = true;
      // Clear verification code after successful verification
      user.verificationCode = null;
      await user.save();
  
      res.json({ msg: 'Verification code verified' });
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(err.message);
      res.status(500).send('Server Error');
    }
  });
  
  //Rest Password route
  router.post('/reset-password', async (req, res) => {
    const { email, newPassword } = req.body;
  
    try {
      // Check if user exists
      const user = await User.findOne({ email });
      if (!user) {
        return res.status(400).json({ msg: 'User not found' });
      }
  
      // Hash new password
      const salt = await bcrypt.genSalt(10);
      user.password = await bcrypt.hash(newPassword, salt);
  
      // Save new password to database
      await user.save();
  
      res.json({ msg: 'Password reset successful' });
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(err.message);
      res.status(500).send('Server Error');
    }
  });
  
  

module.exports = router;


//user.js
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  email: { type: String, required: true, unique: true },
  password: { type: String, required: true },
  accountType: { type: String, enum: ['Admin', 'Paid', 'Free'], default: 'Free' },
  verified: { type: Boolean, default: false }
});

const User = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);

module.exports = User;

const express = require('express');
const connectDB = require('./config/db.js');
const cors = require('cors');
const proxyMiddleware = require('./middleware/Proxy.js');
const app = express();

// Connect to MongoDB
connectDB();

// Middleware
app.use(cors()); // Enable CORS for all routes
app.use(express.json()); // Parse JSON bodies
proxyMiddleware(app); // Apply proxy middleware

// Routes
app.use('/api/auth', require('./routes/auth.js'));

// Define port
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send('Hello, welcome to the API server!');
});


// Start server
app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Server is running on port ${PORT}`);

// backend/config/db.js

const mongoose = require('mongoose');
require('dotenv').config({ path: '' });


const connectDB = async () => {
  try {
    await mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGODB_URI, {
      useNewUrlParser: true,
      useUnifiedTopology: true,
    });
    console.log('MongoDB Connected');
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error connecting to MongoDB:', error.message);
    process.exit(1); // Exit process with failure
  }
};

module.exports = connectDB;


{
  "name": "backend",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "Percy",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@sendgrid/mail": "^8.1.3",
    "axios": "^1.6.8",
    "bcryptjs": "^2.4.3",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "dotenv": "^16.4.5",
    "express": "^4.19.2",
    "express-validator": "^7.0.1",
    "http-proxy-middleware": "^3.0.0",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^9.0.2",
    "mongoose": "^8.3.1",
    "nodemailer": "^6.9.13",
    "nodemon": "^3.1.0",
    "sendgrid": "^5.2.3"
  }
}

{
  "name": "frontend",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.17.0",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "axios": "^1.6.8",
    "bootstrap": "^5.3.3",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-bootstrap": "^2.10.2",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}


Also here are the raws for the request and resoponse headers:
HTTP/1.1 408 Request Timeout
x-powered-by: Express
access-control-allow-origin: *
connection: close
date: Mon, 22 Apr 2024 20:18:29 GMT
content-length: 0

POST /api/auth/register HTTP/1.1
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br, zstd
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 58
Content-Type: application/json
Host: localhost:3000
Origin: http://localhost:3000
Referer: http://localhost:3000/register
Sec-Fetch-Dest: empty
Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors
Sec-Fetch-Site: same-origin
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/123.0.0.0 Safari/537.36
sec-ch-ua: "Google Chrome";v="123", "Not:A-Brand";v="8", "Chromium";v="123"
sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0
sec-ch-ua-platform: "Windows"


If you can share your registerValidation code since you are adding it as a middleware it might be hanging there if next is not called
